# Parts Relationship with: Year, Make, Model & Trim

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Developing an auto parts website using Laravel. User should be able to enter Year, Make, Model, Trim of their car and system should show all parts that fits the entry

So far I have been able to relate the Year/Make/Model/Trim tables. I also have the categories Table working with its sub categories.

Challenge is I want to create a Parts Table but I am not sure how to link it with Year/Make/Model/Trim. A part can fit many vehicles so I imagine there has to be a pivot table for fitment.

Can anyone give me clues or idea of best approach?

Comment: You have a table of years?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need a many-to-many relationship table. On one side will be what you have now (year/make/model/trim), and the other for the parts. No need for a pivot table/query. This table should have foreign keys for each of the tables (year/make/model/trim/product) and a unique key that includes all of the columns.

Comment: Although not incorrect, I disagree with SloanThrasher's approach. All you need is a table which records the part_id, and the model_ids to which that part applies: `part_id,model_id`

Comment: @Strawberry Yes I do have an Year table. Relates with Make_Year , Model_Year & Trim_Year.

Comment: @Strawberry. I agree that I need a relation table for parts and model/trim. Would that be part_id, model_id or part_id, trim_id? What about the year. How does it feature in all this?

Comment: i suspect that the answer depends slightly on whether we're talking about a US or European context.